# Выбор и структура классов по БЭМ

Tags: html, css, stylus, бэм

Пытаюсь правильно выбрать классы по `БЭМ` + что бы не было каскадности в `css`. Для `css` использую `stylus`, так что могу писать конструкции типа:

```
.items
  border none
  &__li
    color cornflowerblue
    &_column-2
      margin-left 33px
    // ??? что делать с & span-2 ???
  // ??? что делать с & span-2 ???
// ??? что делать с & span-2 ???
```

Сам проблемный `html`:

```
<li class="items__li-2 items__li items__li_column-2">
    <input id="photons" type="checkbox" name="items" value="photons" checked="checked" class="items__photons items__input-checkbox items__input-checkbox_column-2"/>
    <label for="photons" class="label-photons items__label items__label_column-2 items__label-photons">New 
        <span class="label-photons__span-2 items__photons-span">photons </span>
        <span class="label-photons__span-3 items__photons-span">detector</span>
    </label>
</li>
```

И проблема здесь в том, какой лучше задать класс для `span`. Для написания кода в `stylus` удобнее `items__label-photons__span-2` -- но по `БЭМ` нельзя задавать элемент элемента, а очень много классов задавать элементу не хочется тоже, да и если не `items__label-photons__span-2` -- тогда в коде неудобно будет иметь для `span-2` код стиля где-то далеко от `label-photon`, т.е. в конце `items`, например.

Как все таки лучше в данном случае задать классы по `БЭМ` (и чтобы в стилях не было каскадности)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбей элемент на более простые элементы, то есть если у тебя есть

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">
    <label class="block__content__label"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="block__bottom">
    <label class="block__bottom__label"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Разбей его на 2 блока:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-content">
    <label class="block-content__label"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="block-bottom">
    <label class="block-bottom__label"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

так ты и в стилусе сможешь спокойно все это в одном {} описывать и именование не нарушаешь по факту. Тоже по началу не понимал как это должно работать, пришел к такому варианту.

Кроме того, ссылаться надо только на родителя, а не на полную структуру блока, по этому можно (а может и нужно) и так:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__content">
    <label class="block__label"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="block__bottom">
    <label class="block__label"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. по сути так и делаю. но проблема здесь в том, что в средине stylus кода для блока items будет невозможно добраться до span и придется все в конец писать отдельным блоком кода... т.е. в идеале items__label-photons__span-2 -- но БЭИ не дает такого...

Comment: Не понял, почему нельзя будет добраться? .items &-label-photons &__span-2

Comment: ну или `.items &__label-photons &-span-2`

Comment: .items &__label-photons &-span-2 --да, вроде так каскадности нет. попробую... отпишусь с результатом позже.

Comment: бэм и учит тому, что бы разбивать огромные блоки на более простые. Меньше вложенность, если есть глубокая вложенность, то есть родитель, а есть его дети, не более того, в именовании не должно быть такого, что у тебя есть родитель, потом дочерний, дочерний-дочернего, ... Если такое встречается, разбивай этот блок ещё на более мелкие, они могут иметь "префикс" родителя .item &-child (.item - префикс), но в целом он должен быть самостоятельным. Так ты можешь и в один блок стилей их вписать и при этом они являются более мелким ответвлением общего, хоть и не дочерним (если по именованию судить)

Comment: значит, я зделал верно, задав класс уровня блока для label - 'label-photons' и, соответственно, класс элемента этого блока для внутреннего span: 'label-photons__span-2', верно?

Comment: @CodeGust, есть опыт проекта с full-stack BEM, но хоть убей сейчас не смогу сказать как там глубокая вложенность работает. Но на сколько понимаю, именно с точки  зрения читаемости такого класса, то все хорошо, если у него конечно есть родитель с классом `.label-photons`, а не структура типа `.label .label__photons .label-photons__span-2` (то есть по сути нет родителя `.label-photons`)